# Autoloading Namespace after Use keyword

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

How would I go about autoloading a class after having used the `use` keyword?

e.g.

```
use Code\Store\Core\Store;

$_STORE = Factory::Get( "Store" );
```

My autoloader goes looking for `Store.php` when I want it to go looking for `/Code/Store/Core/Store.php`

Is there a way to expand a namespace after having used `use`? Or autoload it during the use definition? Or is my only option to use the full namespace when getting a class from the factory?

Comment: As you're passing a string to the factory function, it isn't namespace aware: `use Code\Store\Core;

$_STORE = Factory::Get( __NAMESPACE__ . "\Store" );`

Comment: Ah, I get your point.  But wouldn't \_\_NAMESPACE\_\_ return the current namespace, not necessarily that of Store?

Comment: `__NAMESPACE__` returns the current namespace, and it is being concatenated with the literal string "Store" before it is passed to the Factory class Get() method

Comment: Right but Store doesn't exist in the current namespace it resides in Code\Store\Core\.

Comment: Which is why my suggestion modified the `use` clause to `Code\Store\Core`

Comment: That'll change the current namespace to Code\Store\Core?

Comment: Yes, it would... but it's either that, or you pass the fully namespaced classname manually to Factory::Get() as `$_STORE = Factory::Get( "Code\Store\Core\Store" );`

Comment: I tried it out and it doesn't seem to have that effect.

Comment: OK, it's what I do; but if it doesn't work for you then I can't help

Comment: Thanks anyways. I always appreciate new ideas.